VSCode JS Library autocomplete not working when imported on TS file
I installed PURE JS library on npm
it dont have @types or d.ts file
and I imported it. library works as excepted but VSCode autocomplete wont work
I tried just importing it with tsconfig as following:
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6", 
    "module": "Node16", 
    "strict": false, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": true, 
    "checkJs": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node16", 
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "baseUrl": "." 
} ...

it all worked as excepted
using ES6 style importing works, CommonJS style import works
but vscode wont autocomplete anything
I googled it but I only get `JS autocomplete not working on JS file
